# Partitioning with Spark Graphframes

Tags: apache-spark, graphframes

I'm working with a largish (?) graph (60 million vertices and 9.5 billion edges) using Spark Graphframes. The underlying data is not large - the vertices take about 500mb on disk and the edges are about 40gb. My containers are frequently shutting down due to java heap out of memory problems, but I think the underlying problem is that the graphframe is constantly shuffling data around (I'm seeing shuffle read/write of up to 150gb). Is there a way to efficiently partition a Graphframe or the underlying edges/vertices to reduce shuffle?

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR** It is not possible to efficiently partition `Graphframe`.

`Graphframe` algorithms can be separated into two categories:

- Methods which delegate processing to `GraphX` counterpart. GraphX supports a number of partitioning methods but these are not exposed via `Graphframe` API. If you use one of these it is probably better to use `GraphX` directly.

  Unfortunately development of `GraphX` stopped almost completely with only a handful of small fixes over the last two years and overall performance is highly disappointing compared to both in-core libraries and [out-of-core libraries](https://code.facebook.com/posts/319004238457019/).
- Methods which are implemented natively using Spark `Datasets`, which considering limited programming model and only a single partitioning mode, are deeply unfit for complex graph processing.

  While relational columnar storage can be used for efficient graph processing naive iterative `join` approach employed by `Graphframes` just don't scale (but it is OK for shallow traversing with one or two hops).'

  You can try to repartition `vertices` and `edges` `DataFrames` by `id` and `src` respectively:

  ```
  val nPart: Int = ???

  GraphFrame(v.repartition(nPart, v("id")), e.repartition(e(nPart, "src")))
  ```

  what should help in some cases.

Overall, at it's current (Dec, 2016) state, Spark is not a good choice for intensive graph analytics.

Comment: Appreciate the insight. I found that I can boost performance by creating a custom column in the edge dataframe using the GraphX [partition schema](http://note.yuhc.me/2015/03/graphx-partition-strategy/) and partitioning on that.

Comment: @John I couldn't figure it out, do you have an example on how to do the partitioning on a custom column?

Comment: @John Can you share the update on How you resolved this performance issue ?

Comment: @John +1 for a coding example describing how you implemented the partition schema

Answer (score 1):

Here's the partial solution / workaround - create a UDF that mimics one of the partition functions to create a new column and partition on that.

```
num_parts = 256
random_vertex_cut = udf.register("random_vertex_cut", lambda src, dst: math.abs((src, dst).hashCode()) % num_parts, IntegerType())

edge.withColumn("v_cut", random_vertex_cut(col("src"), col("dst")).repartition(256, "v_cut")
```

This approach can help some, but not as well as GraphX.